# Reflection API (Type of an object)

Tags: java, reflection

How can I get the type of an object in java using reflection if the object name is in a string and we do not know what is in the string? I want to ask that if user enters an object name which is already declared, how do I get it's type?

```
Person per = new Person("umer", 12);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String str = br.readLine();
```

If user enters per, I want to get the name of the class i.e person..
What should I do?

Comment: Note how the example points to the user entering the name of a VARIABLE, not the name of a class. That cannot be done, named variables only exist for the purpose of compilation. If you want to give a name to an object which you must later look up, consider using a HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("my.class.from.String");
```

**EDIT**

To be able to access a class by name, you would have to stick them into a Map:

```
Map<String, Person> myPersons = new HashMap<String, Person>();

myPersons.add("umer", new Person("umer", 12));
myPersons.add("cedb", new Person("cedb", 13));

String myName = //Capture user input here

String myClassName = myPersons.get(myName).getClass().getCannonicalName();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "my.class.from.String" exactly?

Comment: This could be any fully qualified class name as a String.

Comment: there will the name of object not the name of a class,,, how can i get class name of that object

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help:

```
object.getClass().getDeclaringClass();
```

from java doc:

> If the class or interface represented by this Class object is a member of another class, returns the Class object representing the class in which it was declared. This method returns null if this class or interface is not a member of any other class. If this Class object represents an array class, a primitive type, or void,then this method returns null.